# How to import BitmapTextureAtlas in Andengine?

Tags: android, import, bitmap, andengine

i added this line.but it gives error.how to import it?

```
 import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.TextureAtlas;
```

Comment: What kind of error? You need to specify the problem better to get an answer.

Comment: "you must create TextureAtlas class"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextureAtlas is an abstract class, try importing

```
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
```

or

```
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas;
```

depending on which one you are using

If you using Eclipse and it is configured properly, you should be able to just delete that line and Eclipse will add the correct import statements - at least it does on my system.

Comment: i tried but it still same.when i use last version of andengine,it's ok but i wanna use older version and i wanna import these:

      import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BitmapTextureAtlas;
      import org.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.bitmap.BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas;

Comment: if you mean the GLES1 branch when you say "older version", those package names are completely different, as in org.anddev.andengine.opengl.texture.atlas.buildable.BuildableTextureAtlas; - notice the "anddev" in there - you can't mix GLES1 and GLES2 - well, I guess you can, but you shouldn't